# issue with sql query conversion to hibernate query

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Hi I have like month wise table jan, feb..dec and I have locatin and actioncount fields in each with location repeated in each table.

I have this query written roughly in SQL, I have the month domain objects, Now I have to convert it to Hibernate Query (HQL or Criteria api or anything else..). How do I convert it?
The count of months is provided as a list and is variable like so
the below sql is from this list `monthsToQuery = [oct,nov,dec,jan]` .. this is also variable list. 
It can be [feb, mar, apr] or [jul]

```
select loc, sum(tcount) from (
                   (select location as loc, sum(actioncount) as tcount from oct group by location) left-join 
                   (select location as loc, sum(actioncount) as tcount from nov group by location) left-join 
                   (select location as loc, sum(actioncount) as tcount from dec group by location) left-join 
                   (select location as loc, sum(actioncount) as tcount from jan group by location)

                   ) group by loc
```

I am doing left joins because I dont want to loose any locations among different months.

Addition: I also have a date range as input. So far I am getting a list of months from the range and getting results for each month separatley. I need to write the query to give the final required result in 1 query.
here is what I have until now:

```
// sTblList - list of all month domains in the date range.. 
 def getSummary(sTblList,SfromDate,StoDate,res_id, groupCol,sumCol){
       try{
         Date fromDate = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", SfromDate);
         Date toDate = new Date().parse("yyyy-MM-dd", StoDate); 

        def resourceInstance=Resources.get(res_id);
        sTblList.each{
         def OnemonthList=it.createCriteria().get {    
            eq('graresource',resourceInstance)
            between('currentdate', fromDate, toDate)        
            projections {  
            sum(sumCol,'tcount')
            groupProperty(groupCol)      
                }                  
            }      

        return sumMap  // sumMap should have all months results combined
    }
```

I read some places that instead of nesting criterias I can also use alias in criteria. I am new to this..
does anyone know further?

Comment: I would start by normalizing the schema, and have a single table with a month column. Everything will be much easier this way.

Comment: we have separated the data into 12 tables for performance and summation purposes, it is a huge table otherwise with 50 million records.

Comment: With an index on the month column, it will probably be much faster than joining on all those tables. 50 million is no so much for a good database.

Comment: I do agree 50 million is not much for good database like oracle or some others.. but we want to make a generic schema and code accordingly which is good for any database.. like MySQL etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your model uses inheritance

```
abstract class Month
{
    string location;
    int actionCount;
}

class January extends Month
{
}

session.CreateCriteria(Month.class)
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Location"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("ActionCount")))
```

or an interface

```
class Month implements HasActionCount
{
    string location;
    int actionCount;
}

session.CreateCriteria(HasActionCount.class)
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Location"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("ActionCount")))
```

Updated: the following works for NHibernate and SQLite (should also work in Hibernate)

```
class Month
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Location { get; set; }
    public virtual int ActionCount { get; set; }
}

class January : Month
{
}

class February : Month
{
}

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="ConsoleApplication1.January, ConsoleApplication1" table="`January`">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Location" />
    <property name="ActionCount" />
  </class>
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="ConsoleApplication1.February, ConsoleApplication1" table="`February`">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Location" />
    <property name="ActionCount" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

// works as expected
IList<Month> months = session.CreateCriteria<Month>().List<Month>();

// returns the location and sum of each month though
IList<Object[]> sums = (Object[])session.CreateCriteria<Month>()
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.GroupProperty("Location"))
        .Add(Projections.Sum("ActionCount")))
    .List();
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip.. so the month domain class would store all all location and action counts from the 12 monthly tables is it? Because the inserts in the 12 tables are done through a nightly job that runs in the background, so that insert process has to be done even for this base domain?

Comment: you have to map all months seperatly but hibernate is smart enough to know that when you query for the base class it has to query for all inherited classes and you get back a list of inherited classes (january, ...). the sql generated should look like your query. same goes with interfaces, i am not sure if the interface has to be mapped though, maybe not.

Comment: I also just read on some related posts that the class month needs to be abstract?

Comment: dunno but it would makes sense

Comment: I am going to try this.. but i have another selector in the query which is a date range. I give that range also as an input to each of the nested query. Suppose I also put date field in the month class, so irrespective of the months in the range, it would query all 12 tables I suppose, which I want to avoid. I have added my implementation which I have so far..

Comment: Hi I did try the solution and it is creatng the appropriate table structure when we define the base class as abstract... i.e. it creates tables only for the inherting classes - jan, feb..etc, does not create table for Month class. But how do I query the month class to get data from all child classes.. right now with the statement Month.createCriteria().list{} does not work, it says cannot use list on Month class. But Jan.createCriteria().list{} works.. I really need this to work so all my queries will become very simple

Comment: i had similar things working. i will try it out your case later this day when i have time.

Comment: maybe having the class as Abstract or an Interface makes a difference?

Comment: hmm, I am using HibernateCrtieriaBuilder - a wrapper around the Hibernate api for use in grails/groovy application. May be all features are not supported in this builder api. I know for sure that restrictions are not there, and the queries are written without them... But I can use the classic way of java too...by retrieving the hibernate session.